# CSS pseudo element transform is choppy

Tags: html, css

I have a basic CSS transition where I rotate a pseudo `::after` element and increase its width on hover. However the element transition is choppy and skips most of the animation halfway through.

#### Issue reproduced in a <kbd>[Code Pen](http://codepen.io/agconti/pen/xnIsu)</kbd>.

I've tried using `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to solve the issue but I cant seem to stop the transition flash. Any ideas?

Transition css:

```
a {
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #db421c;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 4px 0px #fff;
       -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 4px 0px #fff;
         -o-box-shadow: inset 0px 4px 0px #fff;
            box-shadow: inset 0px 4px 0px #fff;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;


}
a + a {
    margin-left: 20px; 
}
a::after{
    width: 20px;
    height: 1px;
    content: " ";
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(55%, 10%);
       -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(55%, 10%);
         -o-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(55%, 10%);
            transform: rotate(90deg) translate(55%, 10%);

    webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
           transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;


}
a:last-child::after {
    content: none;
}

a:hover {
    color: black;
}

a:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(100%, -20px);
       -moz-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(100%, -20px);
         -o-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(100%, -20px);
            transform: rotate(180deg) translate(100%, -20px);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I isolated the issue to the `translate` transformation; I wasn't sure how exactly to fix it, although I have a feeling the solution is in the [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) property. The only working solution I was able to come up with was to use positioning in order to move the pseudo elements. The same rotation is being used, we are just making use of the `absolute` positioning in order to translate the elements. This method doesn't have any apparent issues given that the parent element is relatively positioned. This method should also work for elements with varying widths.

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gGktd) - it achives the exact same effect without the choppiness.

Instead of `translate(55%, 10%)`, use `top: 10px`/`right: -22px`

And instead of `translate(100%, -20px)`, use `top: 22px`/`right: 0px`

**Updated CSS**

```
a::after {
    width: 20px;
    height: 1px;
    content: " ";
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    top: 10px;
    right: -22px;
}
a:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    top: 22px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer and explanation +1. Any inkling as to how `transform-origin` could solve such issues in the future?

Comment: @agconti Not really; I'd have to do some research. However; it's worth noting that the original transition you had worked in FF without any choppiness (same with IE10!). I therefore think it might have just been a rendering bug with Chrome? That's what you were using too, right?

Comment: yeah of course! I'm surprised this bug is only in chrome and not any of the other browsers. Either way thanks for your help!